# How do I find rows where two column values are switched?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a table with three columns: StartingId, EndingId, and TripCount. The starting and ending ids are the PKs of locations where the trip starts and ends, respectively. The TripCount contains an integer representing the number of times people have traveled between the starting location and ending location.

There will be times when the ending id of one trip becomes the starting id of another trip. The counts will likely also be different when reversing the starting and ending ids.

Here's some sample data:

```
StartingId   EndingId   TripCount
100          200        1023
101          300        5214
200          100        600
650          200        100
```

How do I return only rows that are the reverse trip of another trip and the TripCount. My desired results:

```
StartingId   EndingId   TripCount
100          200        1023
200          100        600
```

Comment: You join on starting and ending...using an alias back to the same table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You join back to the table itself using a different alias.  You want one table's StartingId to equal that same table's EndingId and vice versa.

```
Select 
      t.StartingId, 
      t.EndingId, 
      t.TripCount 
FROM 
      MyTable t 
INNER JOIN 
      MyTable t2 
ON
      t2.StartingId = t.EndingId AND t2.EndingId = t.StartingId
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3d945/4)

Comment: You need include the alias for the field to avoid ambiguous.  `Select t.startingid`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: You have 5k rep. You can just edit that in

Comment: @juergend Im still shy about updating other ppl answer specially JonH have 4x more rep than me :P

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Feel free, I can always roll them back ;).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an exists clause:

```
select startingID
     , endingID
     , tripCount
  from myTable t
 where exists (select 1
                 from myTable t2
                where t2.startingID = t.endingID 
                  and t2.endingID = t.startingID)
```